# Makefile:647: all-recursive Error 1 appearing in make for MSYS2 MINGW64

Tags: mingw, mingw-w64, msys2

I'm building LHAPDF in MSYS2 MINGW64 with the following the installation instructions given in https://lhapdf.hepforge.org/install.html and am getting as far as the `make` line in the first code box. I am receiving the error according to

```
Paths.cc: In function 'void LHAPDF::setPaths(const std::string&)':
Paths.cc:38:5: error: 'setenv' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'getenv'?
   38 |     setenv("LHAPDF_DATA_PATH", pathstr.c_str(), 1);
      |     ^~~~~~
      |     getenv
make[2]: *** [Makefile:628: libLHAPDFPaths_la-Paths.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/c/Users/jacck/Onedrive/Documents/uni/year 4/mphys/pdfstuff/LHAPDF-6.5.4/src'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:647: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/Users/jacck/Onedrive/Documents/uni/year 4/mphys/pdfstuff/LHAPDF-6.5.4/src'
make: *** [Makefile:522: all-recursive] Error 1
```

When googling this error I came across that it may have been an issue with permissions so I ran MSYS2 MINGW64 again as administrator and came across the same error. Initially, I had to build `make` myself and did so using an answer [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/MechanicalKeyboards/comments/8oe8ap/help_msys2_and_make_command/). That allowed `make` to start doing its thing just fine up to this error. I also tried `make install` right after the error because `make` seemed to go through a portion of what it needed to go through just fine. However, this returned the exact same error.

I'm running this on windows 11 OS. What is this error and where might it have come from?

Comment: Looks like LHAPDF can't be built natively for Windows. You might want to try WSL instead.